# How to extend a dictionary of Protocol values keyed by string?

Tags: swift, dictionary, collections, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

I have a dictionary, `[String: ComponentObject]()` in Swift 2 and I have been unable to write an extension for this type. However, when I make `ComponentObject` a `class` instead of a `protocol`, then it works as expected.

Here is a playground that demonstrates the basic setup for the dictionary:

```
import Foundation

protocol ComponentObject {
    var name: String { get }
}

private var _idPrev = 0;
private func defaultName(baseName: String) -> String {
    return baseName + String(++_idPrev)
}

class Thing : ComponentObject {
    let name: String

    init(name: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name ?? defaultName("thing")
    }
}

class OtherThing : ComponentObject {
    let name: String

    init(name: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name ?? defaultName("other")
    }
}

let w = Thing()
w.name

let m = OtherThing()
m.name

var d = [String: ComponentObject]()
d[w.name] = w
d[m.name] = m

let c = d["other2"]!

c.name
```

When I write the extension like this:

```
public extension Dictionary where
    Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: ComponentObject {
    public func getByPath(path: Key) -> Value? {
        // TODO: Some other stuff...
        return self[path]
    }
}
```

I get an error when I call getByPath:

```
let c2 = d.getByPath("other2")!
// Error: Using ComponentObject as a concrete type conforming to protocol
// 'ComponentObject' is not supported.
```

Apple states that "Because it is a type, you can use a protocol in many places where other types are allowed" [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID275) and shows examples of using protocols as the value in a collection [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID279). So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found [the answer](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/496048b1d646de018d05d80c700fa9b4c02620b39be9588010cd4b4c4abad01d) elsewhere and I will update this question with it if nobody else wants to do so. According to the source (on IRC), "you can use protocols to hack around the inability to write `where Value == ComponentObject`..."

Comment: Alternative solution from the same source on IRC, "you can either add all the Dictionary methods you need to use to the protocol, like I did with subscript, or you can just cast `self` to `Dictionary<Key, Value>` inside your code" to which they added "all kinda ugly" :) I know. I'm learning!